# Draw Scatter Plot Octave

Tags: matlab, octave, scatter-plot

I have 2 datasets and a line :

for example :

```
dt1X = [1:30];
dt1Y = [1:30];

dt2X = [1:30];
dt2Y = [0.5:0.5:15.0];

line = [2 1]; % y= 2 + x;
```

I want to draw these two dataset and line in same graph with **different colours**.How can I do that?

I tried the line below to change a color but it gave this error : invalid value for array property "cdata"

```
hold on;
scatter(dt1X,dt1Y,[],"r"); %this line give error
scatter(dt2X,dt2Y,[],"g");
hold off;
```

**EDIT:**

```
    hold on;
    scatter(dt1X,dt1Y,[],[],"r");
    scatter(dt1X,dt1Y,[],[],"g");
    hold off;
```

Result : No error but both datasets draw with blue dots...

using "r" and 'r' Didn't change anythinh it works same in both situation.

Comment: In Matlab, replace double quotes (`"`) by single quotes (`'`). Other than that, I get no errors

Comment: Try another `[],` before the `"r"`.

Comment: works for me with Octave 3.7.7+ (I don't have the stable version around to test).

Comment: @David by adding another [] parameter I gave no error but. It draws the two dataset same colour(blue).

Comment: @LuisMendo I try (") and (') but it doesn't change the function behaviour.

Comment: Which `graphics_toolkit` and Octave version are you using? I tried in Octave 3.6.2 (win XP, compiled for VS2010) with `qt`, `gnuplot` and `fltk`, and all three worked OK.

Answer (score 0):

To clear the figure first add

```
clf
```

before

```
hold on;
scatter(dt1X,dt1Y,[],[],"r");
scatter(dt1X,dt1Y,[],[],"g");
hold off;
```

then you will see that nothing is plotted. So replace these lines by

```
hold on;
scatter(dt1X,dt1Y,"r");
scatter(dt1X,dt1Y,"g");
hold off;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also rearrange your code like this:

```
dt1X = [1:30];
dt1Y = dt1X;

line = [2 1]; % y= 2 + x;

dt2X = dt1X;
dt2Y = line(1) + (line(2) * dt2X); % y= 2 + x;

clf
hold on
plot(dt1X,dt1Y,'r');
plot(dt2X,dt2Y,'g');
```

Comment: Thank you for answers, The code was just sample. I need to draw something more complex. I solved the problem using "plot" function instead of scatter.  plot(X,Y,"x","color","r") works well.